# sort JSON by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I know this must be relatively simple, but I have a dataset of JSON that I would like to sort by date.  So far, I've run into problems at every turn.
Right now I have the date stored as `this.lastUpdated`.
I have access to jquery if that helps, but I realize the .sort() is native JS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format is your date field?

Comment: look here similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-a-json-array

Comment: JSON is a serialized format (a string). I don't think you can do anything to it until you convert it to an object (eval or custom js framework function).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Assuming that you have an array of javascript objects, just use a custom sort function:

```
function custom_sort(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.lastUpdated).getTime() - new Date(b.lastUpdated).getTime();
}
var your_array = [
    {lastUpdated: "2010/01/01"},
    {lastUpdated: "2009/01/01"},
    {lastUpdated: "2010/07/01"}
];

your_array.sort(custom_sort);
```

The Array `sort` method sorts an array using a callback function that is passed pairs of elements in the array.

- If the return value is negative, the first argument (`a` in this case), will precede the second argument (`b`) in the sorted array.
- If the returned value is zero, their position with respect to each other remains unchanged.
- If the returned value is positive, `b` precedes `a` in the sorted array.

You can read more on the `sort` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Unserialized JSON is a non-array object. `.sort()` is only available on arrays.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote! It was an accident. I was not paying attention when I was clicking on the page and now I cannot change it.