# Sort JSON Object by date value

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, date, object

I have an object in javascript

```
Object {HIDDEN ID: "06/03/2014", HIDDEN ID: "21/01/2014"}
```

I want to be able to create a new object that will have it sorted by recent date.

Like so:

```
SortedObject {"HIDDEN ID" : "21/01/2014", "HIDDEN ID" : "06/03/2014"}
```

I know how I could achieve this with an array but I dont know how to iterate through objects to sort by date.

Any help is much appreciated

EDIT:

Now I Have this code.

```
for(var x=0; x<folderList.length; x++){
                    retrieveAllFilesInFolder(folderList[x], function(){
                        var arr = []; 
                        for(var i in fileListObj) { 
                           var d = fileListObj[i].split("/");
                           arr.push({"id": i, "date":(new Date(d[2],d[1]-1,d[0]))}); 
                        }
                        arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a.date < b.date;});
                        console.log(arr); 
                    });
                }
```

However my output is not sorted bydate.

```
Object 1 id: "hiddenID1", date: Mon Nov 18 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Object 2 id: "hiddenId2", date: Thu Mar 06 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Object 3 id: "hiddenId3", date: Thu Sep 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859239/sort-json-by-date

Comment: JSON is a serialization format; "JSON objects" are strings. What you have are normal objects.

Comment: You can find some useful answers to this topic here: **[Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759127/2247494)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant sort an object as it contains key value pairs & not serialized items.

You must first construct an array & then sort it.

```
var obj = {"a" : "21/01/2014", "b" : "06/03/2014"};

var arr = []; 

for(var i in obj) { 

   var d = obj[i].split("/"); 

   arr.push({"id": i, "date":(new Date(d[2],d[1]-1,d[0]))}); 
}

arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a.date.valueOf() > b.date.valueOf();});
```

The result will be a an array `arr` sorted by date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I now have this running however it has not sorted them. I have done console.log(arr) and it shows as an array holding many objects each object has an id and a date.

Comment: Yes, and arr should be sorted.

Comment: No it was not, I cant get it working right now haha it showed the array in the console before now it doesnt.

Comment: Object 1 date: Mon Nov 18 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Object 2 date: Thu Mar 06 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Object 3 date: Thu Sep 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

This is not sorted

Comment: Does this work? `arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a.date.valueOf() > b.date.valueOf();});`

Comment: This may have indeed worked. However sometimes I am running my code and it prints the whole list of objects, and sometimes it prints only 1 object and sometimes none at all. It always prints '[]' in the console though. Im a bit stumped.

Comment: Ok it has worked however it seems to be backwards,  is there a way to reverse the order? :P, as Object 24 has the most recent date, I would like Object 0 to have the most recent instead.

Comment: change `>` to `<` in the sort function

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not sure why I am getting nearly 300 objects, It is repeating a ids/dates so many times, any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

you can't "sort" JSON objects; the only thing you could do would be to get the values into an array and sort the array. i assume the two "hidden id"'s are two distinct fields because your example is not valid JSON.

Comment: Yes they are, If I take the values out, how do I then match the date back with it the correct 'hidden id'?

Comment: I think it's best if you provide an example of what your result is expected to be. You can't sort objects so `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` and `{"b": 2, "a": 1}` are the same thing, if that's what you want you can't have it.

Comment: My expected result would be to have a new object with the ids sorted by date.     {"id5" : "02/01/2014", "id3" : "01/01/2014", "id1" : "05/01/2013"}

Comment: @Joe — As this answer says, you cannot sort JSON objects. They are, by definition, unordered. Arrays have order, objects do not.

Comment: Ok then, it is not possible to put the dates into an array and sort them after, match the dates with their relevant ids?

Comment: Sure it is, but if you put them back into an object afterwards, the order will be lost.