# Sort an Object of objects (JSON) according to date parameter using ECMA5 JavaScript and find the latest object with a "success" as parameter

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I am a bit stuck. First off, I know there are similar questions, and I have tried  various different options, but I am simply missing something. I have not had to do this type of method before, so I would appreciate your help and kindness.

I know I should use (I think) `Object.keys` and `.map`, and a function that looks something like this:

```
function comp(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.result.date).getTime() - new Date(b.result.date).getTime();
}
```

but I am struggling to get it to work.

**I have tried:**

```
var uptime = $scope.frequencyData.production_deploys;

var myObjects = Object.keys(uptime).map(function (itm) {
    return uptime[itm];
});

var arr = [];

for (key in uptime) {
    uptime[key].time = key;
    arr.push(uptime[key]);
}

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time);
});
```

But this created an `array` with no dates.

**I have tried:**

```
uptime = Object.keys($scope.frequencyData.production_deploys);
```

But this created an `array` with only dates

**So here is my Question:**

**STEP 1**: How can I sort an `object` of `objects` ({{}, {}, {}} (JSON) according to the date `parameter`, and then

**STEP 2**: Find the **last date** where the `object` has a `parameter` of **success**

**STEP 3**: And then assign this to a `var`?

**This is my JSON data (`object` of `objects`):**

```
{
  "production_deploys": {
    "2017-07-08": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-09": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-10": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 3
    },
    "2017-07-11": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 10
    },
    "2017-07-12": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 2
    },
    "2017-07-13": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 2
    },
    "2017-07-14": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-15": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-16": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-17": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 3
    },
    "2017-07-18": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 10
    }
  },
  "pull_requests": {

  },
  "test_deploys": {

  },
  "uptime": {

  }
}
```

The data I would like to sort after retrieving the data, would be `$scope.frequencyData.production_deploys`.

**Desired output would be**: $scope.lastScuccessfulProductionDeploy = the correct object.date;

**Some refs I have looked at:**

[sort JSON by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859239/sort-json-by-date)

[Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: I am well aware of similar questions, but I am struggling to make it work. Please be patient. :)

Comment: Object properties aren't ordered. What you can do is push each key-value pair in an array so you can sort the items.

Comment: @onmyway Well, apparently you are not aware of the *answers* then. Because they tell you that you cannot order the content of plain JavaScript objects.

Comment: @onmyway - To avoid being marked as a duplicate, please be specific about how you failed to apply the lessons learned from other similar questions.

Comment: @FredGandt i will update my question. Thank you.

Comment: @onmyway, why do you need sortign if you use only one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object properties aren't ordered. What you can do is filter the `production_deploys` items that have `success` properties (and greater than 0). Next is to change the keys to `Date` objects. Finally, you sort the array, latest first, and get the first item.

```
var sorted = Object.keys(data.production_deploys)
  .filter(function (deployDate) {
    return data.production_deploys[deployDate].success &&
           data.production_deploys[deployDate].success > 0;
  })
  .map(function (deployDate) {
    return new Date(deployDate);
  })
  .sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.getTime() - a.getTime();
  });

var latestSuccessfulDate = sorted[0];
```

```js
var data = {
  "production_deploys": {
    "2017-07-08": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-09": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-10": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 3
    },
    "2017-07-11": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 10
    },
    "2017-07-12": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 2
    },
    "2017-07-13": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 2
    },
    "2017-07-14": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-15": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-16": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 1
    },
    "2017-07-17": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 3
    },
    "2017-07-18": {
      "failures": 2,
      "success": 10
    }
  },
  "pull_requests": {

  },
  "test_deploys": {

  },
  "uptime": {

  }
};

var sorted = Object.keys(data.production_deploys)
  .filter(function (deployDate) {
    return data.production_deploys[deployDate].success &&
           data.production_deploys[deployDate].success > 0;
  })
  .map(function (deployDate) {
    return new Date(deployDate);
  })
  .sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.getTime() - a.getTime();
  });

var latestSuccessfulDate = sorted[0];

console.log(latestSuccessfulDate);
```

Comment: Thank you dork! You made my day. :)

Comment: @onmyway no problem. But I think `Nina Scholz`'s answer is better (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45192973/769326). Just add a `new Date(r or a)` if you want the `Date` object.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the given answers with bad big O (filtering, mapping, sorting), you could use a single loop approach with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var data = { production_deploys: { "2017-07-08": { failures: 2, success: 1 }, "2017-07-09": { failures: 2, success: 1 }, "2017-07-10": { failures: 2, success: 3 }, "2017-07-11": { failures: 2, success: 10 }, "2017-07-12": { failures: 2, success: 2 }, "2017-07-13": { failures: 2, success: 2 }, "2017-07-14": { failures: 2, success: 1 }, "2017-07-15": { failures: 2, success: 1 }, "2017-07-16": { failures: 2, success: 1 }, "2017-07-17": { failures: 2, success: 3 }, "2017-07-18": { failures: 2, success: 10 } }, pull_requests: {}, test_deploys: {}, uptime: {} },
    result = Object.keys(data.production_deploys).reduce(function (r, a) {
        return !data.production_deploys[a].success || r > a ? r : a;
    }, '');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is actually the better (best?) answer 

Answer (score 1):

To sort your object of objects, you should create a outside list of keys.
This because Javascript does not guarantee that the keys of an object are sortable.

```
var sortedKeys = Object.keys(myObject).sort(mySortFunction);
```

When you want to access this object you use a function that point to this list.

If your object changes, you should update the list accordingly.

The point 2 is trivial, you don't need any kind of order, just browse the object kesy and find the last date with the property value you're looking for.

```
var lastDateObject = null;
var lastDate = null;
for (let keyName in myObject) {
    if (elementHasSuccess(myObject[keyName]) && compareDates(lastDate, keyName)) {
          lastDateObject = Object.assign({}, myObject[keyName]);
      }
}
```

Or something like this, that solves the third point too.

**UPDATE**

The function that are used to order a list should have the following signature:

function compare(a, b) {
    if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
        return 1;
      }
      // a must be equal to b
      return 0;
    }

Get from Mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

As in your case you're comparing Dates you could first convert string in date:

```
var dateA = new Date(a);
var dateB = new Date(b);
```

Then return the difference of the timestamps (milliseconds):

```
return dateA.getTime()-dateB.getTime();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Mario. How would the `mySortFunction` look like? This is part where I struggle. I am not sure how to correctly create a list of keys, and then to use and iterate through it.

Comment: Thank you for the update and answer! i am still trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

one more solution..

```
var tt1 = Object.keys(tt.production_deploys)
.map(function(ke) { if (tt.production_deploys[ke].success == "1") { tt.production_deploys[ke].date = ke; return tt.production_deploys[ke]  } })
.filter(function (itm) { return itm !== undefined; })
.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.date > b.date ? a.date : b.date; })
```

considered "success == 1" you can change if it needs other criteria. works fine with current date format, but might need slight changes to adapt other date formats.