# How to sort array of objects based on date in Angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects as shown below :

```
this.filteredData = [
    {'id': 1, 'date': '04-05-2018'},
    {'id': 2, 'date': '29-03-2018'},
    {'id': 3, 'date': '03-04-2018'},
    {'id': 4, 'date': '24-07-2018'},
    {'id': 5, 'date': '19-08-2018'},
    {'id': 6, 'date': '13-09-2018'},
]
```

and am trying to sort the array based on the `date` on click of the button

```
    this.filteredData.sort(function(a, b){
      return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
    });
```

but the array is not sorting..

Where am i doing wrong? need help

Comment: Try without new Date . Do like b.date - a.date only.

Comment: Your dates are not valid. `29-03-2018` will be attempted to make a date for `03-29-2018`. - Do a `console.log(new Date(b.date))` do see what I mean in the console.

Comment: Check what you are doing. Dump out the Date instances. Are they right? Date constructor only recognises a few formats. Use Date.parese().

Comment: You date format is wrong, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859239/sort-json-by-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new Date it assumes the order of month then day, hence your dates such as `29-03-2018` will be seen as `03-29-2018` and cause `invalid Date`.

You can simply specify the date in reverse as `2018-03-29` that way it will see it correctly.

Using the [**string split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string/split) method you can split the date value by `-` resulting in an array `["29","03","2018"]`

Then reverse the array using [**array reverse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) resulting in `["2018","03","29"]`

Finally, join the elements back into a single string using [**array join**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with `-`, resulting in `"2018-03-29"`

```js
var filteredData = [
    {'id': 1, 'date': '04-05-2018'},
    {'id': 2, 'date': '29-03-2018'},
    {'id': 3, 'date': '03-04-2018'},
    {'id': 4, 'date': '24-07-2018'},
    {'id': 5, 'date': '19-08-2018'},
    {'id': 6, 'date': '13-09-2018'}
]

filteredData.sort(function(a, b){
      return new Date(b.date.split('-').reverse().join('-')) - new Date(a.date.split('-').reverse().join('-'));
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your date formats are invalid - 03-04-2018 is ambiguous - is that the third of April or the fourth of March?

Assuming you can't easily alter the source data, you can flip it inside your sort function into a ISO 8601 syntax:

```
this.filteredData.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date(b.date.split('-').reverse().join('-')) - new Date(a.date.split('-').reverse().join('-'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use year, month and day as separate parameters on `new Date()`

> new Date(year, month [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [,
>   milliseconds]]]]]);

```js
let filteredData = [
    {'id': 1, 'date': '04-05-2018'},
    {'id': 2, 'date': '29-03-2018'},
    {'id': 3, 'date': '03-04-2018'},
    {'id': 4, 'date': '24-07-2018'},
    {'id': 5, 'date': '19-08-2018'},
    {'id': 6, 'date': '13-09-2018'},
];


filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
  let formatDate = (dt) => {
    let [d, m, y] = dt.split('-');   //Split the array
    return [y, m - 1, d];            //Return on the as year, month and day order. Not m - 1 because js accepts 0-11 month. 
  }

  return new Date(...formatDate(b.date)).getTime() - new Date(...formatDate(a.date)).getTime();
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Doc: [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to write this in console:

```
new Date("29-03-2018")
```

You will get invalid date:
Invalid Date

This:

```
new Date("04-05-2018")
```

Thu Apr 05 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)

will get you wrong month (you get April instead May).
But, if you write date like:

```
new Date("03-29-2018")
```

Thu Mar 29 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)

you will get the correct date. 
**So,replace month and day in order to work!** :)