# How to sort array by JSON date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array. I have to sort an array in reverse order by its given enrolled date.

Below is function I have written

```
 getDevicesList(devices, user) {
    let activeDevices = [];
    const pendingDevices = [];
    const historyDevices = [];
    devices && devices.forEach((device) => {
        if(device.get("status") === DEVICES_STATUS.INACTIVE && !UserUtils.isStatusArchived(user.get("status"))) {
            pendingDevices.push(device);
        } else if(device.get("isRecentlyUsed")) {
            activeDevices.push(device);
        } else {
            historyDevices.push(device);
        }
    });

    var sorted_meetings = historyDevices.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.enrolledDate) < new Date(b.enrolledDate));
    console.log(sorted_meetings);

    activeDevices = [...pendingDevices, ...activeDevices];
    const noDevices = activeDevices.length === 0 && historyDevices.length === 0;
    return { activeDevices, historyDevices, noDevices };
}
```

I have tried moment to convert JSON date into normal date. But it didnt work for me.

```
var sorted_meetings = historyDevices.sort((a,b) => {           
  var dateA = moment(a.enrolledDate).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
  var dateB = moment(b.enrolledDate).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
  return new Date(dateA).getTime() - new Date(dateB).getTime()
}).reverse();
```

This is my array which I have to sort.

```
historyDevices : (4) [Map, Map, Map, Map]
  0: Map
     size: 8
    __altered: false
    __hash: undefined
    __ownerID: undefined
    _root: ArrayMapNode
     entries: Array(8)
      0: (2) ["id", 81054566]
      1: (2) ["make", "iPhone"]
      2: (2) ["model", 5]
      3: (2) ["status", "ACTIVE"]
      4: (2) ["nickName", "abc abc"]
      5: (2) ["lastUsedDate", "2018-04-13T18:41:59.193Z"]
      6: (2) ["enrolledDate", "2019-03-23T03:54:19.620Z"]
      7: (2) ["isRecentlyUsed", false]
     length: 8
     __proto__: Array(0)
      ownerID: OwnerID {}
     __proto__: Object
     __proto__: KeyedIterable
1: Map {size: 8, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
2: Map {size: 8, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
3: Map {size: 8, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Result: I expect all the array elements should come by reverse enrolledDate order.

Comment: you can sort the array using moment, rather than create date objects, try `return dateA - dateB`

Comment: have you tried this answer...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859239/sort-json-by-date

Comment: What is the input here?

Comment: Remove the reverse. Instead try changing the return statement order in sort function

Comment: No need to parse string in to dates. The ISO8601 format used here is already sortable. Just sort on the string value directly.

Comment: Hi All, thank you for the reply. I have added the function I have written.

Comment: @MikeBrockington it's [the format parameter for displaying am/pm in a string](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var sorted_meetings = historyDevices.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.enrolledDate) - new Date(a.enrolledDate));
```

Comment: Hi Horia, I have tried this, but no luck.

I am updating my code. adding the function. can you please check where i am getting wrong