# How can I sort an array full of objects by the date (which is represented by index 0-23 in the key attribute of each element)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

The following array is copied from the console and should demonstrate the structure of the array. It is an array with multiple objects, which all have a unique `key`: each key is a combination of a date and a unique identifier.

My question is, how can I sort the array so that I have all the objects sorted by the `date` (which is represented by index 0-23 in the `key` of each element)?

```js
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: '2023-01-22T04:00:00.000Z63c4a2b248f0a56684d4ffcd',
ref: null, props: {…}, …}
1: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: '2023-01-21T06:56:00.000Z63cb70559d1aa33902535ba2', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
2: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: '2023-01-30T18:00:00.000Z63cc668315bcc1b222020168', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
3: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: '2023-01-28T20:00:00.000Z63cc6c2415bcc1b2220201c6', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
4: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: '2023-01-27T19:00:00.000Z63cc6c5515bcc1b222020228', ref: null, props: {…}, …}

length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort JSON by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859239/sort-json-by-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this format, you can probably just sort comparing dates as strings (i.e. lexicographically). Something as simple as this could be fine. The rest of the string (i.e. the guid after the date) will be irrelevant because the order is determined by the first leading part:

```js
data.sort((a, b) => a.key < b.key ? -1 : 1)
```